# How does SQL Self-Join performs it's operation?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand SQL Self-joins. I have the following table Weather

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | recordDate | temperature |
+----+------------+-------------+
| 1  | 2015-01-01 | 10          |
| 2  | 2015-01-02 | 25          |
| 3  | 2015-01-03 | 20          |
| 4  | 2015-01-04 | 30          |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

(Source: [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/rising-temperature/description/))

I want to get a table containing data with higher temperatures compared to its previous dates (yesterday).
so, I performed this mysql query.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *
FROM Weather w1
ORDER BY w1.recordDate)

SELECT c1.*, c2.*
FROM cte c1
JOIN cte c2 ON c1.Id = c2.Id+1
```

But it gives me this Output which I was not expecting.

```
| id | recordDate | temperature | id | recordDate | temperature |
| -- | ---------- | ----------- | -- | ---------- | ----------- |
| 2  | 2015-01-02 | 25          | 1  | 2015-01-01 | 10          |
| 3  | 2015-01-03 | 20          | 2  | 2015-01-02 | 25          |
| 4  | 2015-01-04 | 30          | 3  | 2015-01-03 | 20          |
```

I was expecting this output for above query.

```
| id | recordDate | temperature | id | recordDate | temperature |
| -- | ---------- | ----------- | -- | ---------- | ----------- |
| 1  | 2015-01-01 | 10          | 2  | 2015-01-02 | 25          |
| 2  | 2015-01-02 | 25          | 3  | 2015-01-03 | 20          |
| 3  | 2015-01-03 | 20          | 4  | 2015-01-04 | 30          |
```

Could somebody please help me understand why this happend?

Comment: For "previous" see `lag`. note that an ordering expression within a table expression is redundant.

Comment: c1.Id = c2.Id+1 is the wrong way round...voting to close as typo.

Comment: I don't think "help me understand" is a typo - I think OP genuinely is asking to understand

Comment: `ORDER BY` w/o `LIMIT` in subquery/CTE makes now sense because it will be ignored in outer query.

Answer (score 1):

It make sense because c1.id(2) = c2.id(1)+1

Answer (score 0):

Your join (`JOIN cte c2 ON c1.Id = c2.Id+1`) says:
Look in C2 for records where the ID is the same as C1 + 1.

So, if C1 ID is 1, it is looking in C2 for 2.

That's why you get this result.